# what is the correct syntax to declare a data literal in pig

Tags: apache-pig

I'd like to create a row/data in the pig script itself.  What's the syntax for declaring a literal?

I tried

```
dists = {umdid1:'2215848', show1:'Judge Judy', umdid2:'608492', show2:'Judge Alex', common_count:'271.0', count1:'3395.0', count2:'952.0',dist:'0.06648675'};
```

but that throws a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible. You can declare constants to be added as fields in a relation but you cannot manufacture a relation within the script. The simplest solution would be to LOAD the data from some sort of file.